# How to use a named function with for each and this

Tags: javascript

I have found that not using anonymous functions has made my code more readable and self-documenting by flattening the code into more understandable, standalone functions.  So I'd like to break out the following construct from:

```
function Save() {
   myVal = 3.14 // some arbitrary value
   $('#myID').each(function(index,element) {
      if ($(this).val() === myVal) {}
   });
}
```

Into:

```
function Save() {
   myVal = 3.14 // some arbitrary value
   $('#myID').each(myFunction);
}

function myFunction(index,element) {
   if ($(this).val() === myVal) {}
}
```

The problem with using .bind here, is that you lose the value of $(this) inside the each method, so (I don't think) I can bind myVal to myFunction.

Maybe I could use `element` instead of `this`?

Edit 1: I should have used .myClass instead of #myID for an example selector.

Edit 2: I'm not using bind in the proposed solution because I don't think bind would work.

Edit 3: I appreciate everyone saying that the first example is more readable.  I'm just exploring the language and trying out different thoughts.

Comment: `this` would be the same in both codes, here.

Comment: you do not lose the value of `this`.. you lose access to the `myVal` variable..

Comment: In my opinion, the first one is more readable.

Comment: `$('#myID').each` is very suspect : do you have more than one element with this id ?

Comment: You aren't using `.bind` there.

Comment: You should only have a single element with id myID :)

Comment: Not sure what your point about `.bind()` is, you don't seem to be using it? `this` will work in your example, because the way `each()` calls the callback does set up `this`.  What you *do* lose this way is binding of other local lexicals and that is often a reason to prefer the anonymous function, although you can convert lexicals into function parameters if you want.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Not only is the first one more readable, it also comes with the closure and thus the access to myVal.

Comment: Thanks @drquicksilver!  Yeah, I want to get away from using anonymous functions as much as I can.  My understanding of JavaScript reached a new level when I started naming my functions.

Comment: @Phillip: What's wrong with anonymous functions?

Comment: @RocketHazmat, the problem with anonymous functions is that you get this stairstep looking code where you're multiple levels deep.  I want to flatten out my code so that it's at the 1st level as much as possible.

Comment: @Phillip that's not really a huge deal. You don't want to separate out your functions if you don't need to. Using functions this way (as closures) is not at all strange. It's only if you have multiple, nested, closures that things can get unwieldy.

Comment: Am I the only one bothered by the fact that `$(this).val()` returns a string and therefore never strictly equal to 3.14?

Comment: @Zecc - whenever I post a JavaScript question of StackOverflow, I learn so much.  Is using two equal signs the solution for that, or should I have used parseFloat with $(this).val()?

Comment: @Phillip It is generally recommended to avoid == altogether as it is considered evil due to [its relatively complicated rules for type coersion and edge cases](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/notes/note-2-ecmascript-equality-operators/#strict-codecode-and-non-strict-codecode-equality). In this particular case where the type of `myVal` is known to be a non-zero number it may not be too terrible, but using `parseFloat` will always make your code more resilient and your intent clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And what about :

```
function Save() {
    myVal = 3.14 // some arbitrary value
    $('#myID').each(myFunction(myVal));
}

function myFunction(myVal) {
    return function(index, element) {
        if ($(this).val() === myVal) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: This is clever, but the call to `myFunction(myVal)` would throw me off if I was reading this code. :)

Comment: @JuanMendes Oh, I got it :) But it's just that I usually favor obvious code as far as maintenance is concerned.

Comment: @VivinPaliath This is at the heart of JS, functions returning functions, JS developers need to know this... Teach them to fish

Comment: @JuanMendes True. I guess I'm just more used to code being obvious. I mainly work in Java where things are not as dynamic. But yes, this is quite Lisp-y and I do like its functional nature.

Comment: But when you say each(myFunction(myVal)), wouldn't it have to be each(function() {myFunction(myVal))})?

Comment: @Phillip no, because `myFunction(myVal)` will execute first and return a function as a return value, which is used as the argument for `each`.

Comment: @Phillip it is a partial function (see for example : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg575560.aspx)...

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie: I've never heard anyone use the term "partial function" before.

Comment: @Phillip hum, yes partial application... Sorry I come from a mathematical world ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You're not losing access to `this`; you're losing access to `myVal` because `myVal` is not known inside `myFunction`, mainly due to that function being defined in a scope that does not have a definition for `myVal`.

What you can do is something like this:

```
function myFunction(index, element, myVal) {
   if ($(this).val() === myVal) {}
}
```

and then:

```
function Save() {
   myVal = 3.14 // some arbitrary value
   $('#myID').each(function(index, element) {
       myFunction.call(this, index, element, myVal);
   });
}
```

This way if you have a lot of logic inside `myFunction`, you can still separate it out and just call `myFunction` from `.each)`'s callback. Not that `myFunction` is being called with `.call` because that way you can pass in an explicit value for `this` (the first argument). Hence `this` is the same `this` that is inside the callback to `.each`.

To be honest though, the first option is much more readable and you really aren't gaining much by splitting your code out like this.

Comment: You're making  `this` be `window` by calling `myFunction()`

Comment: You need to use `element` inside the definition of `myFunction` instead of `this`.

Comment: @JuanMendes whoops, right. I just copied the OP's code. I should have used `.call` and passed in `this` explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

`this` in this context will be the same. The one thing you lose access to is `myVal`. You are right that you can't use `Function.bind` because that does not allow you to specify to keep the original (call time) `this`

Here's how you can pass `myVal` and keep the same `this`, using a modified version of `Function.bind`, that we're calling `myBind`

```
/**
 * Binds the given function to the given context and arguments. 
 *
 * @param {function} fun The function to be bound
 * @param {object} context What to use as `this`, defaults 
 *        to the call time `this`
 * @param {object[]} customArgs Custom args to be inserted into the call
 * @param {number} index Where to insert the arguments in relationship
 *        to the call time arguments, negative numbers count from the end.
          That is, -1 to insert at the end. Defaults to a 0 (beginning of list).
 *        
 */
function myBind(fun, context, customArgs, index) {
      return function() {
          // Default the index
          index = index || 0;
          // Create the arguments to be passed, using an old trick
          // to make arguments be a real array
          var newArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
          // Tack the customArgs to the call time args where the user requested
          var spliceArgs = [index, 0].concat(customArgs); 
          newArgs.splice.apply(newArgs, spliceArgs);
          // Finally, make that call
          return fun.apply(context || this, newArgs);  
      }
}


function Save() {
   myVal = 3.14 // some arbitrary value
   $('#myID').each(
      // myFunction wil be called with myVal as its last parameter
      myBind(myFunction, null, [myVal], -1)
   );
}

function myFunction(index, element, myVal) {
   if ($(this).val() === myVal) {
       // do it here
   }
}
```

To demonstrate the flexibility of this function, let's bind more than one argument, and it should be inserted at the beginning of the call time arguments

```
function Save() {
   var myVal = 3.14, val2 = 6.28; // some arbitrary values
   $('#myID').each(
      // myFunction wil be called with myVal and val2 as its first parameter
      myBind(myFunction, null, [myVal, val2], 0);
   );
}

// Since I don't need element, it's already available as this, we don't 
// declare the element parameter here
function myFunction(myVal, val2, index) {
   if ($(this).val() === myVal || $(this.val() === val2)) {
       // do it here
   }
}
```

This is almost the same answer as Samuel Caillerie. The only difference is that we create a different version of `Function.bind` that doesn't bind `this`, just the arguments. Another  benefit of this version is that you can choose where the insert the bound arguments;

Comment: I don't think `this` inside `myBind` will be what you think it is.  Also, `myBind` will call `myFunction` and set its return value to `.each`'s callback.

Comment: That's interesting.  Writing a bind function.  Now that's thinking outside of the box.

Comment: Why are you doing `[myVal].concat(arguments)`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes, I did forget to wrap it... Thanks.

Comment: To insert `myVal` as the first element in the new arguments. I tried to explain that in the comment for the function

Comment: Shouldn't it be the ***last*** argument?  `myFunction(index,element, myVal)`

Comment: I think the .bind method inserts any new values _before_ the other values.

Comment: @Rocket It could be... The best way is to let the caller decide where to insert the custom argument[s]

Comment: Also, since `arguments` isn't technically an array, `[myVal].concat(arguments)` doesn't do what you'd expect.  You actually get `[myVal, arguments]`, not `[myVal, index, element]`.

Comment: @JuanMendes: I was just trying to make your example consistent (and functional).  Your example has the parameters in one order, but you're calling them in another order.

Comment: @RocketHazmat You're right again, since you're interested, give me a minute to address your points...

Comment: @JuanMendes: Sorry about that, I was just trying to help :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat That's cool, and feel free to suggest any improvements to this last revision.

Comment: @JuanMendes, I'm accepting Samuel Caillerie's answer because it seemed that his was more - I don't know: elegant?  But your myBind function is something that I will study.

Comment: @Phillip More elegant? This is just a more abstracted version of the same answer, explaining how `bind` works. I think you mean that Samuel's answer is easier to digest, which is why you chose it and that makes perfect sense. However, it would require always calling a different function `createHandlerXXX` to achieve the same effect (binding your args).